# how to extract data from image by user

Tags: matlab, io

I want to my program give a image to user and user by mouse choose a pixel,then spatial information of pixel return to program for another process.

how write code for it in matlab ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
A=imread('your image');
imshow(A);
impixelinfo;
[c, r, vals] = impixel;
```

c and r are arrays of all the columns and rows of the part of the image that user clicked on and vals are the RGB values of each point.

Comment: +1.  Never knew about this function!